# ASP.NET MVC Website: Object Moved to Here

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

I have built an ASP.NET MVC web application which works OK on my local machine.
When I publish it, it creates a "Roslyn" directory (as NuGet package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform is installed).

When I uninstall NuGet package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, and I debug the web site, I get the error "Object moved to here".

I also get the same error when I upload the website to the server with the NuGet package installed and browse to it.

Nothing in the event log. Controllers seem to run OK.

Any ideas?

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the MVC views had string interpolations in them (which you can't do in the absence of Roslyn) and weren't reporting any exceptions. Fixed it!